# I went upto here to add an image to my android app but there is an error line

Tags: android, image, android-resources

I went upto here to add an image to my android app but there is an error line:

```
String pathName = "chemistry\2013_03_26\chemistry1.pdf";//Error line
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
View view = findViewById(R.id.container);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
```

Comment: `"chemistry\2013_03_26\chemistry1.pdf";` is not valid path. use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for getting SDCARD path if image is located on SDCARD

Comment: from where you are using image? sdcard?? server?? asser?? drawable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use absolute path with `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalFileDir()`.

You can find more information at [clickHere](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)